# Isolated working environment Debian

Tags: dependencies, debian, libraries, aptitude

I'm working on a Debian based server and I'm trying to install a library using ***aptitude***

The problem is when I do it, the command wants to remove other libraries (I don't know why, but I guess it's because of conflicts) and I'm already using these libraries.

Is there a way to avoid this, like creating some kind of isolated environment where I can remove these libraries without touching the ones I'm using?

Comment: do you mean: a virtual machine or a linux container? then yes, you can do that

Comment: Yes I mean that but I need something I can access to via ssh. If that's possible with any of those, how can I do it?